# function with ajax request that returns empty result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that contains an ajax request and I want this function to return the result of the ajax request. Here is the function :

```
    function get_the_posts(cat) {

        var table = [];

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : get_all_the_posts + '?cat=' + cat
        }).done(function(data){
            table = data.table;
            console.log(table); // (1) There is what I need and it works
        });
        console.log(table); // (2) but there is an empty table

        return table; // empty result
   }
```

I know that ajax is asynchronous that means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow etc. and that's why my first console.log() is displayed after the second one. but I don't know how can I return my table filled by datas returned by the ajax request... i tryed to put the `return` inside the `.done` but it doesn't work...

Can someone help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `get_all_the_posts`?

Comment: are you getting something in console.log(data);

Comment: the location of my php function, but as it works and send back a result, I don't think this is the problem :

Comment: You could force the ajax call to be synchronous by using the parameter `async: false`

Comment: `async:false` works well ! thanks !

Comment: Based on @Zenoo answer, code go first to `console.log(table)` and then to `table= data.table`. Try async: false.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the concept of promises. You are using jQuery, so you could check out this: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Basically what you want is to return a promise that you will return the result of the ajax call (you call that in another function) and then you can work with the result.

For example:

```
$.when(get_the_post).then(do_something_with_it);
```

So instead of returning the table you return the *promise* and in the function `do_something_with_it()` you work with the result.

Comment: `async:false` works but i'll learn about promises, it seems interesting thx

Comment: @CédricCosson: Don't use `async: false` ever. It is not recommended

Comment: @31piy Ok, i'll try promises then thanks